# String Tokenizer issue

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

AM using string tokenizer to delimit the string response by `^`

```
12/30/2011 12:00:00 AM^President^^^159^True^True^True^True^True^False^False^True^True^3/18/2011 12:00:00 AM^True^Jujama, Inc.^^^^True^True
```

but the problem is when `^` delimiter consecutively its skipping that one and adding in to array.
But i want to add space if two `^`delimiters comes.

How to do that?

My code is:

```
 StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(partId, "^");

              while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){

                 String value=tokens.nextToken();
                 userValues.add(value);
                 System.out.println("..."+value);

              }
```

Comment: In general, favour Scanner over StringTokenizer if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User `string.split("^")` instead. Split receives regex, so you can do almost what you want within one line.

Comment: AM using string.split("^") but its not splitting anything

Answer (score 1):

Check out StringUtils from Apache:

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#splitPreserveAllTokens(java.lang.String, char)